# WEB API calls giving 500 error after upgrading to sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, upgrade, asp.net-web-api-routing, sitecore-mvc

Recently, we upgraded to Sitecore 8.0 from Sitecore 7.5. After the upgrade, the Custom Web API calls began returning 500 error codes with the below exception:

```
Message:"An error has occurred."
ExceptionMessage:"ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance."
ExceptionType:"System.InvalidOperationException"
StackTrace:"   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.GetControllerMapping()
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.AddRouteEntries(SubRouteCollection collector, HttpConfiguration configuration, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__1()
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.EnsureInitialized(Func`1 initializer)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__0(HttpConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.CorsHttpConfigurationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3.<AddCorsMessageHandler>b__0(HttpConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.ApplyControllerSettings(HttpControllerSettings settings, HttpConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.GetControllerMapping()
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.AddRouteEntries(SubRouteCollection collector, HttpConfiguration configuration, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, IDirectRouteProvider directRouteProvider)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__1()
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.EnsureInitialized(Func`1 initializer)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.AttributeRoutingMapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<MapAttributeRoutes>b__0(HttpConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.CorsHttpConfigurationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3.<AddCorsMessageHandler>b__0(HttpConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.ApplyControllerSettings(HttpControllerSettings settings, HttpConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)
   at Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Dispatcher.NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerDictionary()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Dispatcher.NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

Routes are registered in `global.asax.cs`:

```cs
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
            {
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                //    name: "DefaultApi",
                //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                //);
            });
            SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

[This solution](http://wp-bartbovendeerdtcom.azurewebsites.net/sitecore-8-webapi-v2-mvc-and-attribute-routing/) worked for us when attempting the upgrade. You should read the post in full to understand what it's doing but in short you will need to create a custom HttpControllerSelector and swap it out with Sitecore's after Sitecore has added all of the routes. Note: None of this summary is originally mine. I gleaned all of this from the linked article.

Just as a side note I highly recommend avoiding an in place upgrade to Sitecore 8. I would say it's almost always a better bet to use a fresh install of Sitecore 8 and then migrate your content via a package. [This blog](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/upgrade-sitecore-7x-to-8) is a great look at the two options.

Comment: It would be better to provide a summary of the solution in the answer, please see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I provided context to both the links. In addition, I'm not going to plagiarize or steal someone else's work. We used that exact article to fix our problem and I'm not going to copy paste it in here.

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed to add the following: `public override IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> GetControllerMapping()
        {
            return _controllers;
        }` to the `CustomHttpControllerSelector`